# Pandoc longtable headers not formatted correctly

Tags: longtable, pandoc

I am using Pandoc to convert markdown to latex. When i try to add a table the header is sometimes not formatted correctly.
Here as an example that displays correctly:

```
| Themenschwerpunkt       | Programmierung der App                                  |
| ----------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------- |
| Ziele und Anforderungen | RE-M 5 Automatisches einlesen der Rechnung per Foto     |
|                         | RE-M 7 Sicherung der Daten                              |
|                         | RE-M 8 Automatische Einkaufsliste                       |
|                         | RE-M 9 Authentifizierung                                |
|                         | RE-M 12 Projektwebsite                                  |
|                         | RE-M 16 Veröffentlichung                                |
|                         | RE-O 3 Rechnungen und Einkauflisten als PDF exportieren |
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Correct Table]

However, the table below looks like this:

[image: Wrong Table]

Here is the code for the second table:

```
| Themenschwerpunkt       | Programmierung der App            |
| ----------------------- | --------------------------------- |
| Ziele und Anforderungen | RE-M 4 Einkaufsliste              |
|                         | RE-M 7 Sicherung der Daten        |
|                         | RE-M 8 Automatische Einkaufsliste |
|                         | RE-M 10 Gruppen                   |
|                         | RE-M 11 Einladungen               |
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: which latex code did pandoc create for the table?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For the first table it generates [this](https://hastebin.com/ruyuvesofa.rb) for the second one it generates [this](https://hastebin.com/xayomigiko.rb). I thought it might be because of the minipages but there are other tables in the document which dont have minipages in them and the generated code looks like the second example but work correctly.

Comment: you will have to run latex a second time so that longtable can adjust the width (but  the coding of both longtables is not really good. One wonder why pandoc doesn't use  p-columns).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you very much it worked! We have a script which only builds latex one time to make it faster so i didn't think about this. Pandoc also does something weird with inline code but i don't know why. But thank you for answering!